# Error in getting Date Conversion MySQL

Tags: mysql

I created a user defined for some purpose in which the logic is failing. That is basically 
adding dates with some logic and finally returning the datetime as return of that function.

Just to make it simple i am showing the error part.
My code is

```
CREATE FUNCTION `BIZZ_fnMergeDate`(
) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
 BEGIN

    DECLARE v VARCHAR(1000);

    SET v = STR_TO_DATE('08/06/2014 06:00 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i');

    RETURN '';

 END //

DELIMITER ;
```

This is just to make an example not the actual code.

This is executed without error. But When it is called it throws the following error

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '08/06/2014 06:00 PM' 0.000 sec
```

But when this particular line

`select STR_TO_DATE('08/06/2014 06:00 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i');`

i took outside and run as a separate query it is running fine.

I am not getting why within function it is not working. Seems weird.
Please help in figuring this.

Comment: shouldn't v be the type date?

Comment: @Leo, tried with both. VARCHAR returns the result perfectly too. Just a note, the solution given by Ollie at least fixes the error that was coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

You may need to change your format string to take account of the PM part of your date/time format:

```
 '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i %p'
```

should do the trick.

Also, stored procedures don't throw runtime errors until runtime, even if it would be possible for a smart compiler to throw them at compile time because they're based on constants. That's a geeky way of saying that MySQL can't tell you've  made an error like this one until you run the stored function.

To answer your question, "how do I get this into 12 AM/PM format" here's what you need to know. `STR_TO_DATE()` converts strings to internal `DATETIME` datatypes. These have many advantages. They're compact, they're searchable, etc. If you try to display such a datatype or implicitly convert it to a text string, you get something like this format:

```
2014-08-06 18:00:00
```

If you want the `DATETIME` rendered into some other format, such as 12 am/pm format, you need to use `DATE_FORMAT()`to do that.

For the operation I think you want

```
DATE_FORMAT(whatever_date, '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i %p')
```

will do the trick.  In your code this becomes

```
SET v = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('08/06/2014 06:00 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i %p'), '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i %p');
```

This is a little strange because it converts from 12 am/pm format back to the same format. But it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey Ollie, this solved the part where the error doesn't come any more. But it got converted to a 24 Hour format. I do need it in a 12 Hour format with AM and PM to it. Used the techniques in date_format, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Still my concern is why the sane stuff which is executed separately it works but not in the function ??

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `BIZZ_fnMergeDate`(
) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN

    DECLARE v VARCHAR(1000);

    SET v = STR_TO_DATE('08/06/2014 06:00 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i');

    RETURN v;

 END //

DELIMITER ;
```